# Surjective map between fundamental group of surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $f\colon S_m\rightarrow S_n$ be a continuous map of degree $\pm1$.
Then the induced morphism $f_\bullet \colon \pi_1(S_m) \rightarrow \pi_1(S_n)$ is onto.

How can I prove this?

I know that the map $f_\bullet \colon H^1(S_m) \rightarrow H^1(S_n)$ is injective,
but I don't see how to conclude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it wasn't onto, the map would factor through a covering space of the codomain. If the covering is infinite, the covering space is noncompact hence has $H^2 = 0$, and the degree is zero; if the covering is finite of degree $d$, the covering map induces multiplication-by-$d$ on $H^2$. In either case you cannot possibly achieve degree $\pm 1$.